# Why three.js particles sprites example performance scales so bad?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to do some particles experiments with `three.js` and I started with [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_particles_sprites).

The example is running smoothly at 60fps with 1000 particles, but stalls around 10 fps when setting the number of particles around 10000 ( just changing line 57 to `for ( var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )` )

I see other examples easily displaying a much larger number of objects smoothly, up to a million? ([example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/))

What is the limiting factor in the example I tried and how could it be scaled to 10000 or 100000 particles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are limited by the overhead of the draw calls. You are issuing 10.000 of them, while you can render the million letters with a single one. 1000 is a lot to begin with. This kind of optimization may not even be possible on the canvas.

Comment: I tried creating a THREE.group instead adding the particles to the group and just adding the group to the scene at once and the performance is the same.
So I don't think it is the issue.

Comment: it doesnt do anything, you are either interested in https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Points or https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferGeometry and `WebGLRenderer`. The group just creates another object in the scene graph. You still have 10k objects underneath it.

Comment: Thanks. That's right. I didn't even notice the sample was not using webglrenderer but canvasrenderer. Using a Points geometry also makes the difference.